# compared with non class/module in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to only include users who have more than 0 `challenges.publish`?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users, @alphaParams = User.select{ |user| user.challenges.publish > 0}.alpha_paginate(params[:letter], {:pagination_class => "pagination-centered"}){|user| user.name}
  end
end
```

Maybe I should use `where` instead of `select`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `joins`, `where` and `distinct` to avoid select same records.

```
User.joins(:challenges).where('challenges.publish > 0').distinct
```

Using ruby methods like `map`, `select` etc. with `active records` method   is bad behavior, because it can provide to n+1 problems or other errors.